# Scalable RDBMS alternative, NoSQL, NewSQL

Tags: database, sql, nosql, mongodb

I am looking for scalable alternative to traditional DBMS like PostgreSQL or MySQL. In traditional databases I don't have the following features:

Auto sharding to ensure linear scalability.
Replication with automatic failover and recovery to ensure high availability.
No single point of failure.
MongoDB looks like good candidate if I can sacrifice transactions.

Also I've looked at several newSQL databases. NewSQL seems suitable for my purposes: VoltDB, TiDB, cockroachDB. But I'm worried about whethever they are production-ready.

May be there are extensions allowing to run postgreSQL or MySQL in clustered mode out of box.

Comment: "*Replication with automatic failover and recovery to ensure high availability*" - Postgres can absolutely do that there are several tools that will help you to implement that. You can do sharding with built-in features in Postgres (using foreign data wrappers and inheritance) - but it's far from being "automatic". For "automatic" sharding you should probably look into [Postgres-XL](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/postgres-xl/) or maybe [BDR](https://2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/bdr/)

Comment: Thanks, Postgres with suitable utils looks like really good approach.

Comment: FYI: transaction support is coming in MongoDB 4.0: https://www.mongodb.com/transactions

Answer (score 1):

[YugaByte DB](https://docs.yugabyte.com/introduction/overview/) is an open-source cloud-native database for mission-critical applications. YugaByte DB supports two popular NoSQL APIs, Apache Cassandra Query Language (CQL) and Redis, in a wire-compatible fashion. It supports single-row ACID (with multi-row transactions coming soon), and has been extensively tested in a number of real-world use cases. **[Automatic sharding](https://docs.yugabyte.com/architecture/concepts/sharding/)** and **[Raft-based replication](https://docs.yugabyte.com/architecture/concepts/replication/)** are built-in features of YugaByte DB. Please see [YugaByte DB architecture documentation](https://docs.yugabyte.com/architecture/) for more details, and see the [quick start guide](https://docs.yugabyte.com/quick-start/install/).